# nodejs check and update database field one day after it was created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, cron

i have mongoose model

```
const BookingSchema = new Schema({
    start_at:{
      type:Date,
      required:true
    },
    end_at:{
        type:Date,
        required:true
    },
    canceled_at:{
        type:Date,
        required:false
    },
    status:{
        type:String,
        enum:["PENDING","APPROVED","NO_RESPONSE"],

        default:"PENDING"
    }},
    {
       timestamps:true
    }
);
```

i need to change `status` field to `NO_RESPONSE` value one day after  it was created if `status` field have not changed to  `APPROVED`

how i can do this using nodejs,mongod?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cronjob in this case

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

const checkBookingStatus = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '0 1 * * *', // every 24 hours
    onTick: function() {
      console.log(`
           Runing a job at 01:00 at America/Sao_Paulo timezone
      `);
      Booking.update({ status: 'PENDING', createdAt: { 
        $lt: new Date(), 
       $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))
     }}, { status: '' })
    },
    start: true,
    timezone: "America/Sao_Paulo"
  });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i need some thing more flexible such a trigger or any thing , i will up vote for your answer and accepting if i don't find another solution

Answer (score 1):

One way to update each record exactly after 1 day is queuing callback function to Nodejs Event loop for each record. But that will be too heavy to do. If you are ok to run a job and update the records that are 1 day old then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-cron.

Comment: thank you for your answer i need something like first way but without callback :) function